# Modify xml element name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

How to change element name from Cust to Customer?

```
<Cust id="1">
  <Name>aaaaaaaaaa</Name>
  <Desc>bbbbbbbbbb</Desc>
</Cust>
```

When I'm using following statement

```
select @myXml.query('/node()[1]/node()') for xml raw('Customer')
```

sql removes attributes

```
<Customer>
  <Name>aaaaaaaaaa</Name>
  <Desc>bbbbbbbbbb</Desc>
</Customer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    @myXml.value('(/Cust/@id)[1]', 'int') AS '@id',
    @myXml.query('/node()[1]/node()') 
FOR XML PATH('Customer')
```

Gives me an output of:

```
<Customer id="1">
  <Name>aaaaaaaaaa</Name>
  <Desc>bbbbbbbbbb</Desc>
</Customer>
```

With the `FOR XML PATH`, you can fairly easily "restore" that attribute that gets lost in the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use replace:

```
replace(replace(@YourXml, '<Cust id', '<Customer id)', '</Cust>', '</Customer>')
```

This is fairly safe, as `<` is not valid as data in XML, it would appear as `&lt;` or an ASCII or UNICODE sequence.

Comment: It's a non-grace method. Other ideas?

Comment: @chomik: XML modification support in SQL Server is entirely "non-grace".  Consider doing this client site. :)